# Solution: Python3 Tkinter Jump from one window to another with back and next buttons

Tags: navigation, python-3.x, window, tkinter

I've been studying tkinter in python3 and find it very hard to find good documentation and answers online. To help others struggling with the same problems I decided to post a solution for a simple problem that there seems to be no documentation for online.

Problem: Create a wizard-like program, that presents the user with a series of windows and the user can move between the windows clicking next and back - buttons.

The solution is:

- Create one root window.
- Create as many frames as you have windows to present to the user. Attach all frames to the root window.
- Populate each frame with all the widgets it needs.
- When all the frames have been populated, hide each frame with the `grid_forget()` method but leave the first frame unhidden so that it becomes the visible one. All the child widgets on the frame will be hidden with the frame.
- When the user clicks on Next or Back buttons on a window, call a subroutine that hides other frames (with `grid_forget()`) and makes the one that is needed visible (with `grid()`).
- When you want the program to end, use the destroy - method for the root window.

So you will be creating a single window and showing different frames on it.

(By the way, the best place to start studying tkinter is: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html)

Here is a sample implementation in Python3. It has 3 simple windows, each with a text label and two buttons to navigate through different windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

# Creates three "windows" that the user can navigate through using Back and Next - buttons.

import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk

def create_widgets_in_first_frame():
    # Create the label for the frame
    first_window_label = tkinter.ttk.Label(first_frame, text='Window 1')
    first_window_label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))

    # Create the button for the frame
    first_window_quit_button = tkinter.Button(first_frame, text = "Quit", command = quit_program)
    first_window_quit_button.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))
    first_window_next_button = tkinter.Button(first_frame, text = "Next", command = call_second_frame_on_top)
    first_window_next_button.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))

def create_widgets_in_second_frame():
    # Create the label for the frame
    second_window_label = tkinter.ttk.Label(second_frame, text='Window 2')
    second_window_label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))

    # Create the button for the frame
    second_window_back_button = tkinter.Button(second_frame, text = "Back", command = call_first_frame_on_top)
    second_window_back_button.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))
    second_window_next_button = tkinter.Button(second_frame, text = "Next", command = call_third_frame_on_top)
    second_window_next_button.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))

def create_widgets_in_third_frame():
    # Create the label for the frame
    third_window_label = tkinter.ttk.Label(third_frame, text='Window 3')
    third_window_label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))

    # Create the button for the frame
    third_window_back_button = tkinter.Button(third_frame, text = "Back", command = call_second_frame_on_top)
    third_window_back_button.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))
    third_window_quit_button = tkinter.Button(third_frame, text = "Quit", command = quit_program)
    third_window_quit_button.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(tkinter.N))

def call_first_frame_on_top():
    # This function can be called only from the second window.
    # Hide the second window and show the first window.
    second_frame.grid_forget()
    first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

def call_second_frame_on_top():
    # This function can be called from the first and third windows.
    # Hide the first and third windows and show the second window.
    first_frame.grid_forget()
    third_frame.grid_forget()
    second_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

def call_third_frame_on_top():
    # This function can only be called from the second window.
    # Hide the second window and show the third window.
    second_frame.grid_forget()
    third_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

def quit_program():
    root_window.destroy()

###############################
# Main program starts here :) #
###############################

# Create the root GUI window.
root_window = tkinter.Tk()

# Define window size
window_width = 200
window_heigth = 100

# Create frames inside the root window to hold other GUI elements. All frames must be created in the main program, otherwise they are not accessible in functions. 
first_frame=tkinter.ttk.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
first_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
first_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

second_frame=tkinter.ttk.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
second_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
second_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
second_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

third_frame=tkinter.ttk.Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
third_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
third_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
third_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(tkinter.W, tkinter.N, tkinter.E))

# Create all widgets to all frames
create_widgets_in_third_frame()
create_widgets_in_second_frame()
create_widgets_in_first_frame()

# Hide all frames in reverse order, but leave first frame visible (unhidden).
third_frame.grid_forget()
second_frame.grid_forget()

# Start tkinter event - loop
root_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what's the question? While yes, you can self-answer, you should do that by posting the answer _as an answer to the question_.

Comment: Just to clarify: I created this thread not to ask a question, but to post a solution to a common problem I have seen asked on many sites.

The first real GUI program i need to create is an "install wizard" and after hours of digging I could not find any sample code online. So when I finally did get my "proof of concept" to work, I decided to post it here in hope that it may help others learning tkinter :)

Comment: @Mikael Hartzell: the point Donal was making is this: the proper procedure for what you are doing is to invent a question, and then provide your answer as an actual answer. So, your question can be as simple as "how do I make a wizard-like window that can cycle between frames with next and back buttons?". Then, all of the code you put in your original question would instead go to an answer.

Comment: Ok will do next time :) This was my first post, so I was not aware of the sites netiquette :)

Comment: If you wanted to put something interactive in the program, such as the user a quiz, or the user entering their name into a text field, then where would you put that in this program? E.g. I want to have the quiz happening on the second screen. Should I put that in the create_widgets_for_second_screen function?

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, Mikael! It did save me a lot of hassle. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

As you've taken the liberty to post an answer as a question.  I'd like to post a comment as an answer and suggest that perhaps you should contribute this to TkDocs (click their [About tab](http://www.tkdocs.com/about.html) and they talk about contributing to the site).

I think it'd be better if that site were to improved with more examples than to turn this site into a cookbook.  I think you can also contribute to the [Active State recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/), and they seem to be the carriers of the torch for Tcl/Tk, so Tkinter stuff makes a lot of sense there too.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, I just did that and sent the code to Mark at TkDocs :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your work- I used it as inspiration for this example that, while extremely light in terms of the content, is a cool way to make an arbitrary number of windows that you can switch between. You could move the location of the next and back buttons, turn them into arrows, whatever you want.

```
from tkinter import *
master=Tk()

class makeframe(object):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i=i
        self.frame=Frame(master)
        self.nextbutton=Button(self.frame,text='next',command=self.next)
        self.nextbutton.grid(column=2,row=0)
        self.backbutton=Button(self.frame,text='back',command=self.back)
        self.backbutton.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.label=Label(self.frame,text='%i'%(self.i+1)).grid(column=1,row=0)
    def next(self):
        self.frame.grid_forget()
        p[self.i+1].frame.grid()
    def back(self):
        self.frame.grid_forget()
        p[self.i-1].frame.grid()

n=7
p=[0]*n
for i in range(n):
    p[i]=makeframe(i)
p[0].frame.grid()
p[0].backbutton.config(state=DISABLED)
p[-1].nextbutton.config(state=DISABLED)
```