# Tkinter navigation - how do you include an interactive game?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to implement a very simple interactive tkinter thing where the user enters money (to pay for a £5 ticket) by pressing a button. It works fine on its own (i.e. the code immediately below), but it doesn't work when I try to put it inside a tkinter program where you can navigate between windows. Run this to see what I mean by the interactive money-entering thing:

```
from tkinter import *

# here I have used the pack() method, but in the later code example I use grid
# so that my code is compatible with the proposed code I copied from the solution (see below)

def MenuScreen(): # screen
    global tkinter
    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    root.geometry("300x100")

    welcome = Label(frame, text="Welcome to the Durahm gardens. Enter an     option:")
    welcome.pack(side="top")


    PurchaseButton = Button(frame,text='Buy a ticket', command=SideScreen1)
    PurchaseButton.pack(side='bottom')

    ManagerButton = Button(frame,text='Change ticket price', command=SideScreen2)
    ManagerButton.pack(side='bottom')


    root.mainloop()


TicketPrice = 5
NumEntered = 0

def SideScreen1(): # purchase ticket 


    def PoundEntry():
        NumEntered += 1 
        global TicketPrice, notice, NumEntered
        print(NumEntered, TicketPrice)
        if NumEntered == TicketPrice:
            root.notice.config(text="Money entered: "+str(NumEntered))
            root.destroy()

        else:
            root.notice.config(text="Money entered: "+str(NumEntered))


    root = Tk()

    root.explanation = Label(root, text="~Enter 1 pound at a time~",     bg="aquamarine",\
                   height=3,width=20, font=(None, 10))
    root.explanation.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

    root.notice = Label(root, text="Money entered: 0", bg="aquamarine",\
               font=(None, 16),height=8,width=30) # font=(None, 15)
    root.notice.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

    root.PoundButton = Button(root, text="Enter £1", 
                   font=(None, 16), height=3, width=13,\
                   command=PoundEntry)

    root.PoundButton.pack(fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()

def SideScreen2():
    ## the manager changes the password
    print("Manager")


MenuScreen()
```

So  far, I have tried to implement the code of [this navigation solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100380/solution-python3-tkinter-jump-from-one-window-to-another-with-back-and-next-but) , which solves the navigating problem, with the interactive tkinter thing, but the two things somehow seem incompatible.

Here is this code. I have left on the comments that were on the original 'navigation solution' code (which you can see in the link above), including my own comments where I have tried to add my interactive pound-entering thing. 
The error I'm getting now is 'NameError: name 'notice' is not defined' but I don't fully understand where I could define 'notice' without that happening:

```
from tkinter import *

def create_widgets_in_first_frame(): # try 
    # Create the label for the frame
     welcome = Label(first_frame, text='(Window 1)Welcome to the Durahm     gardens. Enter an option:')
    welcome.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=N)

    # Create the button for the frame
    PurchaseButton = Button(first_frame,text='Buy a ticket',  command=call_second_frame_on_top) # quit
    PurchaseButton.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, sticky=N)

    first_window_next_button = Button(first_frame, text = "Change ticket price", command = SideScreen1)
    first_window_next_button.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=10, sticky=N)



def create_widgets_in_second_frame():
    # Create the label for the frame 
    second_window_label = Label(second_frame, text='Window 2')
    second_window_label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=(N))


    TicketPrice = 5 # defining the variables
    NumEntered = 0
    # purhcasing the ticket

    def PoundEntry():
        NumEntered += 1 
        global TicketPrice, notice, NumEntered
        print(NumEntered, TicketPrice)
        if NumEntered == TicketPrice:
            notice.config(text="Money entered: "+str(NumEntered))
            print("Passsing")

        else:
            notice.config(text="Money entered: "+str(NumEntered))

    explanation = Label(second_frame, text="(Enter 1 pound at a time)")
    explanation.grid(column=1, row=0)

    notice = Label(second_frame, text="Money entered: 0")
    notice.grid(column=1, row=1)

    PoundButton = Button(second_frame, text="Enter £1", command=PoundEntry)

    PoundButton.grid(column=0, row=1)

    second_window_back_button = Button(second_frame, text = "Back", command = call_first_frame_on_top)
    second_window_back_button.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=10, sticky=(N))
    second_window_next_button = Button(second_frame, text = "Next", command = call_third_frame_on_top)
    second_window_next_button.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=10, sticky=(N))

def create_widgets_in_third_frame():
    # Create the label for the frame
    third_window_label = Label(third_frame, text='Window 3')
    third_window_label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=(N))

    # Create the button for the frame
    third_window_back_button = Button(third_frame, text = "Back", command = call_second_frame_on_top)
    third_window_back_button.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(N))
    third_window_quit_button = Button(third_frame, text = "Quit", command = SideScreen1)
    third_window_quit_button.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=10, sticky=(N))

def call_first_frame_on_top():
    # This function can be called only from the second window.
    # Hide the second window and show the first window.
    second_frame.grid_forget()
    first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))

def call_second_frame_on_top():
    # This function can be called from the first and third windows.
    # Hide the first and third windows and show the second window.
    first_frame.grid_forget()
    third_frame.grid_forget()
    second_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))

def call_third_frame_on_top():
    # This function can only be called from the second window.
    # Hide the second window and show the third window.
    second_frame.grid_forget()
    third_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))

def SideScreen1():
    pass # the manager changes the password 

###############################
# Main program starts here    #
###############################

# Create the root GUI window.

root_window = Tk()


# Define window size
window_width = 200
window_heigth = 100

# Create frames inside the root window to hold other GUI elements. All     frames must be created in the main program, otherwise they are not accessible  in functions. 
first_frame=Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
first_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
first_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))

second_frame=Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
second_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
second_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
second_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))

third_frame=Frame(root_window, width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
third_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
third_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'

third_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=(W, N, E))

# Create all widgets to all frames
create_widgets_in_third_frame()
create_widgets_in_second_frame()
create_widgets_in_first_frame()

# Hide all frames in reverse order, but leave first frame visible  (unhidden).
third_frame.grid_forget()
second_frame.grid_forget()
```

I'm trying to combine two things: firstly, have a wizard-like program that presents the user with a series of windows and the user can move between the windows clicking next and back - buttons. Secondly, I want to put the simple interactive tkinter thing (entering money) onto one of these windows, so that the user can click a button, and then the window changes so that they can purchase the ticket.

I think a completely different method would allow me more easily to implement the ticket payment thing within the navigation program. It is possible that the above code [(reminder link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100380/solution-python3-tkinter-jump-from-one-window-to-another-with-back-and-next-but) makes no sense for what I'm trying to do. What would be absolutely ideal for this navigation program is the following method:

- creating and populating one frame each for every screen
- destroying and creating a new frame the frame when the user presses a button to switch

But by doing the above, that seems to make it impossible to get rid of the root window lingering in the background. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Tkinter isn't designed to have more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows you need to use `Toplevel` for the second and subsequent windows. There's no point in debugging the rest of your code until that is fixed.

Comment: This seems like way too much code to illustrate the problem. Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Ok am working on it - will do an edit soon